# Boundary of Siegel modular variety

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, moduli-spaces, abelian-varieties, siegel-modular-forms

The moduli space of curves has a compactification whose boundary can be understood as the product of moduli spaces of curves of lower genus. Therefore (perhaps naively) one might hope that there exists a compactification of $A_g$ whose boundary can be understood as in terms of the moduli of abelian varieties of lower dimension. Is there any such compactification?

Comment: There are many! This is a long chapter of algebraic geometry. You might have a look at [this paper](https://otaibi.perso.math.cnrs.fr/Ag_Top_Survey.pdf) for instance to get some idea.

Comment: The minimal ("Baily-Borel-Satake") compactification of $\mathcal{A}_g$ has boundary $\coprod_{i<g} \mathcal{A}_i$ (with a certain topology). Maybe that's the sort of thing you want?

Comment: Thank you very much to the both of you! This is exactly what I wanted!

Comment: I unprotected this question because it seems the only reason it got protected was that it happened to be hit by two spam answers by one user, and because I don't see a reason that this question is more likely to receive further spam answers than just any other question.